# about autumn - is it correct?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is this sentence correct with a 'a little before or after' meaning of 'about'?

> I will return about autumn.

Comment: It's understandable, but not very natural, autumn being quite a long period anyway. I would expect someone to say _in about September_ or _later in the year_.

Comment: Or you can say "I will return in the autumn" since that is a broad time span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically correct, but it sounds a little strange.  I think this is for a couple of reasons:

1. Except for a few common expressions, "about" is more commonly used to refer to space than to time (at least in American English.  I believe it's more common in British English).  In my experience, people more often use something like "around" instead of "about" when talking about times.
2. Talking about "a little before or after" something in time is usually done when referring to a particular moment, or a duration of time that is short compared to how far it is away ("about noon", or "around the 1st of the month").
3. "Autumn" is also already a fairly imprecise measurement (it's not a fixed thing on a calendar, but a season that varies from year to year), so adding additional words to make it even less precise is unusual.

The second and third points can be made better in some cases by using the phrase "some time around" instead of "about" or "around" by itself.  The following does sound more natural:

> I will return some time around autumn.

(This is because when saying "return around autumn" the object is "autumn" (a large, imprecise thing) which is then modified by "around" to be even more vague than it was before, which is unusual.  However, "return some time around autumn" actually makes the object "some time" (a very vague thing) which is then modified by "around autumn" to be *more* precise about the time range it's talking about, which is a more common way to specify things (going from more vague to more precise).)